# NullPointerException on getResources() for a CardView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-cardview

I have a problem that bugs me a lot... I need to call a string array in a normal java class in an Android project, but for the love of God I can't figure out how to getResources() over here... I tried some getContext ideas from Google but to no avail... The java file is used to load a CardView's elements with data... Please ask me for more details if needed...

```
public class ChoicesManager {
private  static String[] ChoiceArray;
private static ChoicesManager mInstance;
private List<Choice> choices;



public static ChoicesManager getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new ChoicesManager();
    }

    return mInstance;
}



public List<Choice> getChoices() {
    if (choices == null) {
        choices = new ArrayList<Choice>();
        ChoiceArray = mInstance.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group_iteme); //HOW DO I FIX THIS

        for (String choiceName : ChoiceArray) {
            Choice choice = new Choice();
            choice.name = choiceName;
            choice.imageName = choiceName.replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase();
            choices.add(choice);
        }
    }

    return  choices;
}

}
```

Comment: Nothing stops you creating a ChoicesManager via the constructor, are you sure that you are creating it by calling `getInstance()`? (And by the way, this is not a good way to create a singleton lazily, check out the lazy initalizer pattern in Effective Java Item 73 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)

Comment: Just to get the low hanging fruit out of the way... Did you make sure to call getInstance first so that mInstance gets initialized? Is there any reason to expect that getResources() won't ever return null under normal conditions?

Comment: `ChoicesManager  = new ChoicesManager ();` will work for you

Comment: @BhargavModi where should I put that line of code to try it out?

Comment: okk now you are using singleton than you use before using `getResourece()` like this line `ChoicesManager choicesManager=ChoicesManager.getInstance()'; than use `choicesManager.getResourece();`

Comment: @Syncrtl64 read my above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to getResources()

For accessing `getResources()` in normal java class need to use Context. for getting Context add Context parameter to `getChoices` method:

```
public List<Choice> getChoices(Context mContext) {
    //...
    ChoiceArray = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group_iteme);
   //....
    return  choices;
}
```

Comment: Oh god, thanks for making me figure it out, I did what you've said, and I just gave the context needed in the MainActivity.java like so:           mAdapter = new LessonsAdapter(ChoicesManager.getInstance().getChoices(getActivity().getApplicationContext()), R.layout.card_view, getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Comment: @Syncrtl64: Add Context parameter in `getChoices` instead of in `getInstance` because 1. `getInstance` method is static so need to declare Context as static parameter  . if call `getChoices` method from different activity,service or any other component and `mInstance` is not `null`  probably get invalid context problem.Thanks